# How to get order/transaction id in django-oscar?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I have written my own payment gateway integration module for django-oscar. When user clicks on checkout, he is redirected to my payment gateway page.

Here i need unique order id or transaction id from the django-oscar. I have basket details like basket id, amount etc. But not sure how to get order id or transaction id.

basically I need some unique id to identify the current order.

Comment: What would be the difference between a basket and an order?

Comment: @KlausD so, will basket id work in my case? Will it be unique across the system?

Comment: You have the model and the payment system specs, so you will have to answer that yourself.

Comment: @KlausD. I am new to django-oscar, so not sure if basket id is unique or not.